How to make a discord.py slash command option be optional and not required?
I've been working on my discord bot for quite some time, I've been working on a economy system. And need to make a 'user' option, but need to make this optional so the user can just do '/balance' instead of entering there username.
I've searched about every single possible thing I can, stack overflow, google, etc.
@client.tree.command(name="balance", description="Check the balance of yourself or another user")
@app_commands.describe(user="Who's balance do you want to check?")
async def balance(interaction: discord.Interaction, user: discord.Member):
    if user == None:
        user = interaction.user
    await interaction.response.send_message(user.display_name)

is my code.

I've rolled back your edit. It is not acceptable here to add SOLVED to your question title. You've already told everyone that it's been solved by accepting an answer to it.

Discord.py optional interaction parameter
You can achieve this using Optional from the typing lib.
from typing import Optional

...

@client.tree.command(name="balance", description="...")
@app_commands.describe(user="Who's balance do you want to check?")
async def balance(interaction: discord.Interaction, user: Optional[discord.Member]): # Use Optional on your discord.Member
    if user == None:
        user = interaction.user
    await interaction.response.send_message(user.display_name)

...


